# Images wont upload into a website even if they exist

Tags: javascript, image, api, frontend

The frontend js code won't upload images unless the name is typed out entirely and in double quotations. To show images dynamically, I can not concatenate or "+" parent folder and image name.

My STACK: reactJS, Axios, springboot

I want to call the backend, get a list of filepaths(strings), and dynamically show images on the front end with those file paths. Simple enough. However, every time I try to show the images on the front end, it doesn't work. Firstly this works

THIS WORKS:
`<img src={require(("../fullStackFiles/206_1dbb9a3f-4c43-4ac2-b810-aa6b04d0dcb4_house.jpeg"))} className="img-fluid" alt="house" />`

THIS DOESNT WORK:

```
   const parent = "../fullStackFiles/"
   const name = "206_1dbb9a3f-4c43-4ac2-b810-aa6b04d0dcb4_house.jpeg"
   const symbol = "\""

  <img src={require((test))} className="img" /> 
  const test = symbol.concat(parent).concat(name).concat(symbol).toString()
  const test2 = parent+name;
  const test3 = symbol+parent+name+symbol;
  const test4 = test3.toString();
  const test5 = ( parent.concat(name).toString() );
```

Or any of the other tests I have tried with so many permutations, but I can't just get it to work. And if I can't get it to work with this style, I wont be able to use the data from my API.

API FE

```
    const loadImages = async () => {
     
    const images = await    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/fileSystem/getImages/${id}`);
        
    console.log("loading images called " + images.data);
          setImages(images.data);
      };
```

API BE (SpringBoot)

```
    @GetMapping("/fileSystem/getImages/{propertyId}")
             public String[] downloadMultipleImagesFromFileSystem(@PathVariable long propertyId) throws   IOException {
            System.out.println("FINDING IMAGES CALLED");
            String[] paths = fileRepository.findImagesByPropertyId(propertyId);
            return paths;
        }
```

Please let me know if you have any best practices you would like to share about Springboot and APIs and anything I need to learn.

I am still a junior and eager to learn.

Comment: How does `images.data` look like?

Comment: Hi it is an array of Strings I think, the console log is 
"loading images called 206_W1dbb9a3f-4c43-4ac2-b810-aa6b04d0dcb4_house.jpeg,206_ac9b81f3-3783-4d61-9177-abbae30fbfb1_house.jpeg,206_ac8728ce-17c7-45be-b767-6d28e50da4d6_house.jpeg,206_d524ebe8-9562-4186-bd56-9a65167cd397_house.jpeg"

Comment: @tromgy but oddly enough, when i try to find its type it say undefined. This is super confusing. there are no spaces after the commas, is that normal?

Comment: re "when i try to find its type it say undefined": You're dealing with asynchronous code here; make sure you're trying to find its type *after* it loads, not while the API call is still pending.

Comment: @DanielBeck hi, yeah there was something buggy with it and I manage to fix that part. I returns an object now. But I am still having an issue with getting the image to display, like using filepath dynamically and passing that to src=""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these variable definitions:

```
const parent = "../fullStackFiles/"
const name = "206_1dbb9a3f-4c43-4ac2-b810-aa6b04d0dcb4_house.jpeg"
const symbol = "\""
```

Going through your attempts:

```
const test = symbol.concat(parent).concat(name).concat(symbol).toString()
```

`test` will result in a string which contains a " as its first and last characters, which is incorrect (the quotation marks are to wrap around the string, not to embed inside it!)   Also the `toString()` at the end is redundant, because it's already a string.

```
const test2 = parent+name;
```

`test2` should result in a valid filepath, assuming you define it before you try to use it.   (Your code sample shows you using it before you define it, though I'm not sure the jumbling-together of HTML and javascript in your question accurately represents what you're doing in your code; it should result in syntax errors if you're doing it exactly like you've shown here.)

```
const test3 = symbol+parent+name+symbol;
```

`test3` will have identical output to `test`.  Adding strings together is treated in javascript as concatenation; the problem here is you've incorrectly embedded the quotation marks as part of the string itself.

```
const test4 = test3.toString();
```

`test4` is identical to `test3`; calling `toString` on something that's already a string does nothing.

```
const test5 = ( parent.concat(name).toString() );
```

`test5` is identical to `test2`, but with another redundant `toString` call on things that already strings.

Comment: I see, thank you!!! bult I am still having issues understanding, so you are saying that test2 should be an okay filepath. But let's say I keep my files in a folder outside my react or java project, how would I reference those?

Sorry, i have zero idea about the best practices for file management or if theres a protocol in storing images

Comment: I just read that react will automatically search for stuff inside its PUBLIC folder. i didn't know that. I was thinking of keeping my images outside my java and react folders to emulate S3. Would I have to use absolute path each time then or is there a way to change where my react looks by default?

Comment: i initially keep my images in my backend (JAVA) folder as to be 'closer' to my backend, but maybe thats stupid? i have moved all images to react public folder out of simplicity. haha sorry if i sound dumb, truly a junior dev

Comment: You can host images externally to your project,  but to use them you would need the full URL (including the domain name), not just an absolute path.  React can be configured in many ways but for now, yeah, maybe best to stick with the basics :)

Comment: …and, yes, images are generally considered part of the front end code along with your html, css, and js; the backend is your api and database. (That’s slightly oversimplified but close enough)